# Why can a helicopter fly upside down?

Tags: aerodynamics, bernoulli-equation, aircraft

I saw images and video clips of helicopter flying upside down, so it can't be bernoulli principle or angle of attack of the rotary blades. So how can the upside down helicopter provide lift in this case?

Comment: [Can helicopters fly upside down?](https://engineering.mit.edu/engage/ask-an-engineer/can-helicopters-fly-upside-down/)

Comment: Re "I saw": could you provide some links?

Comment: FYI: The blades of a helicopter rotor, like the propeller blades on any airplane much bigger than a two-seat trainer, have _[variable pitch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-pitch_propeller)_. In the case of a helicopter rotor, [the mechanism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swashplate_(aeronautics)) is designed to respond almost instantly to control inputs.

Comment: Re, "it can't be Bernoulli principle..." Bernoulli's principle is important in aircraft design, but if you hear "Bernoulli" in any popular explanation of "how airplanes fly," then probably are hearing [the same old BS explanation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lift_(force)#False_explanation_based_on_equal_transit-time) that's been making the rounds for about as long as airplanes have been flying in the sky. A flight instructor once told me, "Wings work by _beating the air down._ Bernoulli just explains why some wing shapes do it more efficiently than others."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rotating blades of a helicopter's main rotor are shaped like wings in cross-section. Their angle of attack can be changed by the pilot to make the helicopter climb or descend with a lever called the *collective pitch control*. If you loop a helicopter so it is upside down and then push the collective to descend, the pitch of the blades will move into a position where they will generate lift even though they are upside down. This means that it is at least theoretically possible to fly a helicopter inverted.

Note that the main rotor blade hub assembly of some helicopters cannot function properly unless the helicopter is right-side up and gravity is pulling down on it i.e., the rotor disc is *loaded*. If you *unload* the rotor by flying this type of helicopter in a parabolic arc so the occupants experience zero gravity, it's possible to lose control and then very bad things will quickly happen.

Comment: Yes. Plus, you can fly the helicopter in a loop or roll where the rotor is loaded all the time. It's no different from the same maneuver in an airplane where you can hold a cup of coffee without spilling, even though in mid-maneuver it is upside-down.